# HTML <img/> display notification

Tags: javascript, html, image, notifications

Is there any standard or browser specific way to get a notification for an `img` element being actually displayed ?

The `onload` notification does not account for the image decompression, potential transfer to GPU, and so on.

I'm trying to profile performance problems on an HTML5 application on iPad, which  makes heavy use of `img` elements referencing local images.

I'd like to measure the time spent actually decoding/decompressing the images after they're read from storage.

So far, all I could find is a Mozilla XPCOM interface ([imgIDecoderObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/imgIDecoderObserver)) that probably cannot be used by 'normal' scripts on a page, much less on iOS Safari.